# Using Yii (or Rails) with only REST as a data-source?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, yii

I'm not sure if my question is clear, but here's some explanation:

I must build a web application (with some complexity) that will use no database. Instead, all the data will be retrieved from another application, on the same machine, which manages the DB transactions. It implements a REST API pattern.

My question is : can Yii (or Rails) be useful for me? I first thought about Yii because I'm better with PHP, but the more I read about it and test it, the more I think it has not been designed to do what I need to do. And I have some good experience with Rails, but I'm wondering if it can help me more than Yii...

What would you use to make an application like this? Everything anyways will be in AJAX (mostly)...

Thank you

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're after something know as Active Resource. Available here for Ruby on Rails:
https://github.com/rails/activeresource

And here for Yii:
https://github.com/Haensel/ActiveResource

The Ruby on Rails setup is likely to be more stable, as the Yii version isn't at 1.0 yet. Note: haven't tried either of them yet, but they look like they'll be fun to use :-)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, but somehow couldn't formulate a decent search query about this and never found it! Thank you!

Comment: Sure, glad to help. In the sea of info about active record, you have to know the name you're after :-)